# Converting a string to be used in in-clause Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a string like this ('car, bus, train')
I want to convert it to be used in an in-clause. Basically I want to convert it to 
('car','bus','train'). Please how do I do this in Teradata

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are getting data like that, but if you have no control over that, you can use [STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/dnt1472241157526.html).

```
select t.* from table (strtok_split_to_table(1,'car, bus, train',',')
returns (outkey integer,tokennum integer,resultstring varchar(25))) as t
```

Run by itself, that gives you:

```
outkey  tokennum    resultstring
1       1           car
1       2           bus
1       3           train
```

You can use that as a derived table and join it to the table you want to filter by. Something like:

```
select
<your table>.*
from
<your table>
inner join (select t.* from table (strtok_split_to_table(1,'car, bus, train',',')
returns (outkey integer,tokennum integer,resultstring varchar(25))) as t) dt
on yourtable.yourcolumn = dt.resultstring
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the another way of spliting the input for n number of commas and use IN clause.

`SELECT regexp_substr('car,bus,train','[^,]+',1,day_of_calendar) fields
FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE day_of_calendar <= (CHAR('car,bus,train') - CHAR(oreplace('car,bus,train',',','')))+1;`

Output of the Query

`fields
~~~~~~~~
bus
car
train`

Here is the systax to use in where clause

`SELECT * FROM <your table> 
WHERE yourtable.requiredColumn in 
(
      SELECT regexp_substr('car,bus,train','[^,]+',1,day_of_calendar) fields
      FROM sys_calendar.calendar
      WHERE 
        day_of_calendar <= (CHAR('car,bus,train') -  CHAR(oreplace('car,bus,train',',','')))+1
  );`

Basically what we are doing here is splitting the string for each comma and below function is calculating number of commas in the string

`(CHAR('car,bus,train') - CHAR(oreplace('car,bus,train',',','')))+1`

Comment: Thank you for this